# php preg_match regular expression for arbitrary pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want to validate a pattern with php preg ( `preg_match`). my pattern looks like this:

```
[ [3 or 4 digits] - ][ 7 digits]{1}
```

examples:

```
345-4444444
9800-1120222
1111111
1000000
0233-7777777
```

i tried this:

```
pattern = "/\A[\d{3,4}[-]{0,1}]{0,1}\d{7}\z/";
```

but it is not correct.
please give a correct pattern.

Comment: That's not how square brackets work.

Comment: Also, you don't need to get all explicit with the `{0,1}` -- `?` does the same thing, and people are more used to seeing it.  It's easier to read IMO.  And `\A` and `\z` are a bit rare as well; you generally only see them with multiline patterns.  Use `^` and `$` unless you're doing something with multiline patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^(\d{3,4}-)?\d{7}$/
```

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/aOAyuNsVpH

Comment: I might suggest making the prefix a non-capturing group...other than that, looks good :)